# Keep line breaks in element at web service

Tags: xml, vb.net, web-services, .net-2.0, xmldocument

I have got the following XML structure

```xml
<root>
    <element1>Some text</element1>
    <element2>Text with a
    new line</element2>
    <element3>More text</element3>
</root>
```

I load this XML content in my program like

```vb
Dim MyXmlDocument As New System.Xml.XmlDocument
MyXmlDocument.Load(MyXmlFile)
```

After this the structure is the same like above.

Now I use the document as parameter for a web service method.

```vb
MyService.DoSomething(MyXmlDocument)

<WebMethod()> _
Public Sub DoSomething(ByVal data As System.Xml.XmlDocument)
    'do something with the XML content
End Sub
```

My problem is that the structure is now changed to the following

```
<root>
    <element1>Some text</element1>
    <element2>Text with anew line</element2>
    <element3>More text</element3>
</root>
```

The line break was replaced with an empty string. This should not happen. Is there a possibility that the line breaks will be keeped during the sending via a web service?

The application and the web service are both .NET 2.0.

Comment: Try using xml line breaks ie &#xD;

Answer (score 1):

XML ignores sequences of whitespaces (blank, carriage returns, linefeeds) and merges them to a single whitespace.

One approach is to use  as VKSingla suggests, another would be to enter the text in a CDATA element.

```
<root>
   <element1>
     <![CDATA[
         Some Text
     ]]>
    </element1>
   <element2>
     <![CDATA[
       Text with a <br />
       new line
     ]]>
    </element2>
    <element3>
     <![CDATA[
         More Text
     ]]>
    </element3>
</root>
```